# Postfix - domainkeys=neutral (no sig)

Tags: email, postfix

I have everything else working fine (SPF and DKIM) but I can't get `domainkeys=neutral (no sig)` to pass!

```
domainkeys=neutral (no sig); from=foo.com; dkim=pass (ok)
```

I know what some people are already going to say, it's old and doesn't get used... But I want to get this working. How can I get it to pass?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get Yahoo's domainkeys to pass, because modern MTAs don't implement it. They use DKIM instead. [DomainKeys is deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys).